# SQL Server function to get directory of a .sql file from inside the file

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am working with `SQL Server 2019`. I have a **abc_list_codes.sql** which has bunch of SQL statements. This file is stored in ***c:\project_abc\sql\list*** folder. I can open `SQL Server Management Studio`, then open a `New Query` tab against a database, then open this **abc_list_codes.sql** file and run it successfully.

Now I want to show the directory of that file when that file is run in `SQL Server Management Studio`. Is there a function or a way in SQL that I can write in **abc_list_codes.sql**, so when I run it in `SQL Server Management Studio`, it will return ***c:\project_abc\sql\list*** as output?

Comment: To what end? What do you want to accomplish

Comment: Just want to show the folder where this file is located. The filename with absolute path will also work.

Comment: Show it where? As a result? On a tab?

Comment: No, from the perspective of the SQL, it has no knowledge of where the batch was loaded from. The only way to do that would be to write some kind of SSMS extension. Exactly *why* you would want to do this is another question....

Comment: @DanielA.White yes show it as a result on a tab.